# How does a Philips Hue Tap transmit a radio signal without a battery?

Tags: power, rf, wireless, button

The [Philips Hue Tap](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079P5H2WG) is a remote control for a Philips Hue lighting system. The buttons can be configured to trigger some action on the Hue bridge, such as turning lights on in a particular room.

The interesting thing about the product is that seems that the energy from pressing the button is enough to transmit a radio message to the Hue bridge.

> The Philips Hue tap is powered by kinetic energy, which means that when you press the light switch you generate sufficient energy to control your smart lights. A truly wireless, batteryless, solution.

How does this work? About how much electrical power is generated by pressing the button? What components would be needed to make something similar?

Comment: Piezo transducer as the button probably.

Comment: The *original* wireless TV remote controls had little hammers and ultrasonic tuning forks.  We *still* modulate IR at comparable frequency (though today we differentiate codes by pattern not frequency)

Comment: "uses an energy converter to turn the mechanical action of the user’s clicks into a small amount of current (between 120-210 microjoules at 2V) to power the device’s electronics" https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/08/gallery-dissecting-the-philips-hue-tap-wireless-battery-less-controller/

Comment: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/08/gallery-dissecting-the-philips-hue-tap-wireless-battery-less-controller/